# Kan extensions and orthogonality

Tags: ct.category-theory

$\require{AMScd}$I have the feeling that there is a connection between the existence of a Kan extension in a 2-category ($\bf Cat$  will be sufficient) and a 2-dimensional notion of orthogonality.

Given
$$\begin{CD}
A @>f>> B \\
@VgVV @.\\
C
\end{CD}$$ the existence of $h = lan_gf : C \to B$ still "solves the lifting problem" or "shows that $B$ if $g$-local" (according to your preferred terminology), but only in a weak sense, because $\eta : f \to hg$ is in general neither an identity, nor invertible (although it is still universal).

I am reinforced in this feeling by a few examples:

1. here https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.06469 lax orthogonal factorization systems are defined, and although the 2-dimensional aspect is kept to a bare minimum (hom-categories are simply posets), lax orthogonality is defined exactly via an extension property (see first lines of page 2);
2. In [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404981900219) paper "(ptwise) cocomplete 0-cells" $X$ are defined as those objects of a 2-category $\cal K$ that admit all (ptwise) left extensions; the class of all these $X$'s is treated, there, exactly the same way as an orthogonal class (with the aim to prove, under surprisingly mild assumptions, that it is 2-reflective, i.e. that "cocompletions exist").
3. In the diagram
   $$\begin{CD}
   A @>f>> B \\
   @VgVV @.\\
   C
   \end{CD}$$
   of *morphisms* in a *1-category*, orthogonality is attained precisely if $g^*=\hom(g,B)$ is invertible. Here, the (say, left) Kan extension of $f$ along $g$ exists if $g^*$ *has a left adjoint*.

So,

> How do I make precise this intuition? How do I ground it on these examples? Does the notion of weak orthogonality, of which "being $g$-local" is a particular case, coincide with the lax orthogonality defined in the first paper (in such a way that, say $lan_g$ exists when $B\to *$ is right lax orthogonal to $g$)?

Comment: I don't understand your (3).  When a 1-category is regarded as a 2-category with only identity 2-cells, it seems to me that a Kan extension exists iff there is a *unique* morphism $C\to B$ making the triangle commute.

Comment: Yes, indeed: the condition $g\perp B$ is equal to the existence of the left Kan extension. 2-discreteness gives uniqueness of $C\to B$ for free, right?

Comment: Right, I guess.  I think I don't even know what you mean by $\hom(g,B)$.

Comment: Well, hom(g,B) is the function of sets $\hom(C,B) \to \hom(A,B)$ between the homs in a category, and the category of 1-cells thereof, in a 2-category. I guess my question is: why nobody mentions this? Who comes first, is orthogonality a Kan extension, or rather Kan extension is a weak orthogonality conditions? (I agree I'd have to formulate a precise question to hope for a precise answer, yes (-: )

Comment: Oh, I see.  I think in (3) you should remove any references to the morphism $f$.  What you're saying is that $B$ is orthogonal to $g$ if $\hom(g,B)$ is invertible, and that all left Kan extensions along $g$ into $B$ exist if $\hom(g,B)$ has a left adjoint, and that these two conditions coincide when our 2-category is a 1-category.

Comment: I think I've seen this mentioned.  For instance, when introducing Kan extensions, I think some people say something like "we might ask this triangle to commute, which may not be possible, but we can ask for the next best thing which is a universal 2-cell inhabiting it."  It seems to me you've answered your own first question: the existence of all Kan extensions along $g$ into $B$, in the case when the 2-category is a 1-category, is the same as saying that $B$ is orthogonal to $g$.

Comment: Ok then, but this provides with a seemingly fruitful intuition for what a lax factorization system must be. Why this wasn't explored? Was it? Where? Is the paper in (1)the only place?

Comment: You have a funny way of asking questions, as if it were someone else's obligation to have already explored all potentially interesting parts of mathematics.  If I had to guess, I would guess that "lax factorization systems" are sufficiently different from ordinary ones that the underlying structures have mainly been studied under other names, such as pointwise cocomplete objects, etc.  You might also be interested in algebraic weak factorization systems https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebraic+weak+factorization+system .

Comment: "You have a funny way of asking questions, as if it were someone else's obligation to have already explored all potentially interesting parts of mathematics." You're not the first to tell me this (in essentially the same way). I'm not inclined to take this comment of yours as a negative one, but maybe you are advising me to change manners? I feel many of the questions I have are "simple", so I'm led to believe I'm not the first to find them potentially interesting.

Comment: AWFS are part of what I was thinking: what refinement of the notion of Kan extension corresponds to the algebraicity of a factorization system? And along these lines, how do the notions of cofibrant generation, small object argument, the characterization of subcategories of a given one as orthogonal classes translate into statements about Kan extensions? How do the notions of "pointwise" extension, absolute extension, translate into staments about lax FSs?

Comment: It's a subtle distinction, but if you could find a way of implying only that you think someone else *might* have studied something, rather than that someone (such as the person you're talking to) *should* have done so, then you might raise fewer hackles (like mine).

Comment: I believe John Bourke and Charles Walker are working on essentially this idea. See slide 16 of [this talk](http://www.math.muni.cz/~bourkej/7WAL/7WALslides.pdf) by Walker, for instance.

Comment: I know. It's been years already, and I lost track of this stream of thoughts. I'll leave them the idea, but I'm happy it was a good one.